# TikZ-UML Error When Creating Component Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I use the latest version `tikzuml-HEAD-2013-03-19.tbz` of TikZ-UML from http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/src/. I try to create a component diagram like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlcomponent}[x=0,y=0]{A}

\end{umlcomponent}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: Boolean parameter of key '/tikzuml/component/no coords
>   ' must be 'true' or 'false', not 'false'. I am going to ignore it.

Switching to the older version `tikzuml-v1.0b-2013-02-01.tbz` again solves the problem, but this is not an option since I need relative positioning, which is only included in the latest version.

Is there any newer version available which fixes this problem or is there any other fix for it?

---

Sorry for editing the question, not being the author. But being unable to comment yet, this was the only possibility(?)

I ran into the same problem as well and found the error in the code, which causes the troubles. 
In tikz-uml.sty, at about lines 2772-2781 there are some if switches badly defined, the proper definition is described here:

[https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-Wörterbuch:_newif](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_newif)

So every switch name has to begin with an "if". Corrected this, I don't have any error messages like the reported one any more.

Comment: This is the exactly same example which is given in the newest documentation of this package. Therefore it should work of course. Please make the code really minimal (just one package and documentclass `article`). If the error persists, do a report to Mr. Kielbasiewicz. I don't know about a newer version of this package.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code above and also wrote to Mr. Kielbasiewicz. Maybe he or anyone else has an idea.

Comment: I haven't found any problem with your example and TiKZ 3.0. Which  TiKZ version are you using?

Comment: `Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`. Sounds quite old, but I actually just use the standard LaTeX distribution coming with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem caused by outdated packages.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. This issue is with the last snapshot of tikz-uml. I had to edit tikz-uml.sty and add lines such as `\newif\ifumlactorWithoutCoords%` to make it work with use cases.